# sql join and group by generated date range

Tags: sql, join, common-table-expression, date-range

I have Table1 and I need a query to populate Table2:

[image]

Problem here is with Date column. I want to know the process of location/partner combination per day. Main issue here is that I can't pick DateCreated and make it as default date since it doesn't necessarily cover whole date range, like in this example where it doesn't have 2015-01-07 and 2015-01-09. Same case with other dates.

So, my idea is to first select dates from some table which contains needed date range and then perform calculation for each day/location/partner combination from cte but in that case I can't figure out how to make a join for LocationId and PartnerId.

Columns:

- Date - CreatedItems - number of created items where Table1.DateCreated = Table2.Date
- DeliveredItems - number of delivered items where Table1.DateDateOut = Table2.Date
- CycleTime - number of days **delivered** item was in the location (DateOut - DateIn + 1)

I started with something like this but it's very like that I completely missed the point with it:

```
with d as
(
    select date from DimDate
    where date between DATEADD(DAY, -365, getdate()) and getdate()
),

cr as -- created items
(
    select 
    DateCreated, 
    LocationId,
    PartnerId,
    CreatedItems = count(*)
    from Table1
    where DateCreated is not null
    group by DateCreated, 
    LocationId,
    PartnerId
),

del as -- delivered items
(
    select 
    DateOut, 
    LocationId,
    ParnerId,
    DeliveredItems = count(*),
    CycleTime = DATEDIFF(Day, DateOut, DateIn)
    from Table1
    where DateOut is not null
    and Datein is not null
    group by DateOut, 
    LocationId,
    PartnerId
)

select
d.Date
from d
LEFT OUTER JOIN cr on cr.DateCreated = d.Date -- MISSING JOIN PER LocationId and PartnerId
LEFT OUTER JOIN del on del.DateCompleted = d.Date -- MISSING JOIN PER LocationId and PartnerId
```

Comment: Can you describe the logic for the delivered column?  The output doesn't seem to match the inputs.

Comment: @GordonLinoff I added description for each column

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
with range(days) as (
    select 0 union all select 1 union all select 2 union all
    select 3 union all select 4 union all select 5 union all
    select 6 /* extend as necessary */
)
select dateadd(day, r.days, t.DateCreated) as "Date", locationId, PartnerId,
    sum(
        case
            when dateadd(day, r.days, t.DateCreated) = t.DateCreated
            then 1 else 0
        end) as CreatedItems,
    sum(
        case
            when dateadd(day, r.days, t.DateCreated) = t.Dateout
            then 1 else 0
        end) as DeliveredItems,
    sum(
        case
            when dateadd(day, r.days, t.DateCreated) = t.Dateout
            then datediff(days, t.DateIn, t.DateOut) + 1 else 0
        end) as CycleTime
from
    <yourtable> as t
    inner join range as r
        on r.days between 0 and datediff(day, t.DateCreated, t.DateOut)
group by dateadd(day, r.days, t.DateCreated), LocationId, PartnerId;
```

If you only want the end dates (rather than all the dates in between) this is probably a better approach:

```
with range(dt) as (
    select distinct DateCreated from T union
    select distinct DateOut from T
)
select r.dt as "Date", locationId, PartnerId,
    sum(
        case
            when r.dt = t.DateCreated
            then 1 else 0
        end) as CreatedItems,
    sum(
        case
            when r.dt = t.Dateout
            then 1 else 0
        end) as DeliveredItems,
    sum(
        case
            when r.dt = t.Dateout
            then datediff(days, t.DateIn, t.DateOut) + 1 else 0
        end) as CycleTime
from
    <yourtable> as t
    inner join range as r
        on r.dt in (t.DateCreated, t.DateOut)
group by r.dt, LocationId, PartnerId;
```

Comment: This second query looks like it might solve my problem, I'll tweak it a little bit since my end result is a bit more complex. Btw, I don't understand purpose of cte from first query, why all these unions?

Comment: I was thinking you wanted to report on all the days between create and out; as I was thinking about it later I realized that you probably didn't want to show days were nothing happened at all. That union was to create a set of rows to represent day 0 up to day 6 (counted from DateCreated). That kind of union is quick way to create a a "table" without having to have an actual table anywhere in the database.

Comment: Actually this part was crucial for my whole problem - `inner join range as r on r.dt in (t.DateCreated, t.DateOut)`... don't know how I forgot that I can actually join using in keyword :)

Comment: I hadn't paid much attention to you attempt above other than to note that `with` was ok and that you were probably using SQL Server. I guess I could have used your DimDate table rather than starting with the other approach. Yeah, I guess you're right that that was pretty much the missing piece. It's nice that you're actually being thoughtful and not just using SO for a free ride.

Answer (score 0):

If to specify `WHERE` clause? Something Like that:

```
WHERE cr.LocationId = del.LocationId AND
      cr.PartnerId = del.PartnerId
```